# Speaking words with Pololu 3pi Robot

Tags: robotics, sound, 3pi

At each instersection I play different music for the compass direction the robot decided to go. Any ideas how to get the robot to speak the words "West", "East", "South", "North"?

```
      if (current_direction == 'W')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a gafaeada");
      if (current_direction == 'E')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a gfgfgfgf");
      if (current_direction == 'S')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a efgefgef");
      if (current_direction == 'N')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a abcabcab");
```

Full code:

```
// The following libraries will be needed by this demo
#include <Pololu3pi.h>
#include <PololuQTRSensors.h>
#include <OrangutanMotors.h>
#include <OrangutanAnalog.h>
#include <OrangutanLEDs.h>
#include <OrangutanLCD.h>
#include <OrangutanPushbuttons.h>
#include <OrangutanBuzzer.h>

Pololu3pi robot;
unsigned int sensors[5]; // an array to hold sensor values
int last1 = 0;
int last2 = 0;
int last3 = 0;
int stop_robot = 0;
int already_stopped = 0;
int use_pattern = 0;
char pattern[] = {'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'L', 'L', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R'};
int pattern_length = 39;
int i = -1;
int pattern_loop = 1;



// This include file allows data to be stored in program space.  The
// ATmega168 has 16k of program space compared to 1k of RAM, so large
// pieces of static data should be stored in program space.
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

// Introductory messages.  The "PROGMEM" identifier causes the data to
// go into program space.
const char welcome_line1[] PROGMEM = "Tim's";
const char welcome_line2[] PROGMEM = "Self";
const char demo_name_line1[] PROGMEM = "Driving";
const char demo_name_line2[] PROGMEM = "Robot";

// A couple of simple tunes, stored in program space.
const char welcome[] PROGMEM = ">g32>>c32";
const char go[] PROGMEM = "L16 cdegreg4";
const char melody[] PROGMEM = "!L16 V8 cdefgab>cbagfedc";
int play_intersection_music = 0;
int be_random = 1;
int speed = 1;
int stop_protection = 0;
int do_calibration = 0;
int variable_speed = 0;
int do_compass = 1;

char current_direction = 'W';

// Data for generating the characters used in load_custom_characters
// and display_readings.  By reading levels[] starting at various
// offsets, we can generate all of the 7 extra characters needed for a
// bargraph.  This is also stored in program space.
const char levels[] PROGMEM = {
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111
};

// This function loads custom characters into the LCD.  Up to 8
// characters can be loaded; we use them for 7 levels of a bar graph.
void load_custom_characters()
{
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 0, 0); // no offset, e.g. one bar
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 1, 1); // two bars
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 2, 2); // etc...
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 3, 3);
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 4, 4);
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 5, 5);
  OrangutanLCD::loadCustomCharacter(levels + 6, 6);
  OrangutanLCD::clear(); // the LCD must be cleared for the characters to take effect
}

// This function displays the sensor readings using a bar graph.
void display_readings(const unsigned int *calibrated_values)
{
  unsigned char i;

  for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    // Initialize the array of characters that we will use for the
    // graph.  Using the space, an extra copy of the one-bar
    // character, and character 255 (a full black box), we get 10
    // characters in the array.
    const char display_characters[10] = { 
      ' ', 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 255     };

    // The variable c will have values from 0 to 9, since
    // calibrated values are in the range of 0 to 1000, and
    // 1000/101 is 9 with integer math.
    char c = display_characters[calibrated_values[i] / 101];

    // Display the bar graph character.
    OrangutanLCD::print(c);
  }
}

void no_stopping() {
  OrangutanLCD::clear();
  OrangutanLCD::print("No\nStopping");  
  delay(1000);
}

// Initializes the 3pi, displays a welcome message, calibrates, and
// plays the initial music.  This function is automatically called
// by the Arduino framework at the start of program execution.



void setup()
{
  unsigned int counter; // used as a simple timer

    // This must be called at the beginning of 3pi code, to set up the
  // sensors.  We use a value of 2000 for the timeout, which
  // corresponds to 2000*0.4 us = 0.8 ms on our 20 MHz processor.
  robot.init(2000);

  load_custom_characters(); // load the custom characters

    // Play welcome music and display a message
  OrangutanLCD::printFromProgramSpace(welcome_line1);
  OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
  OrangutanLCD::printFromProgramSpace(welcome_line2);
  OrangutanBuzzer::playFromProgramSpace(welcome);
  delay(1000);

  OrangutanLCD::clear();
  OrangutanLCD::printFromProgramSpace(demo_name_line1);
  OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
  OrangutanLCD::printFromProgramSpace(demo_name_line2);
  delay(1000);

  OrangutanLCD::clear();
  int bat = OrangutanAnalog::readBatteryMillivolts();
  OrangutanLCD::print(bat);
  OrangutanLCD::print("mV");
  OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);

  delay(2000);
  OrangutanLCD::clear();
  if (!play_intersection_music) {
    //OrangutanLCD::clear();
    OrangutanLCD::print("No");
    OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
    OrangutanLCD::print("Stopping");

  }
  else {
    //OrangutanLCD::clear();
    OrangutanLCD::print("Do");
    OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
    OrangutanLCD::print("Stop");
  }
  // Display battery voltage and wait for button press
  while (!OrangutanPushbuttons::isPressed(BUTTON_B))
  {

    //delay(100);
    if (OrangutanPushbuttons::isPressed(BUTTON_A)) {
      OrangutanPushbuttons::waitForRelease(BUTTON_A);
      OrangutanLCD::clear();
      if (play_intersection_music) {
        play_intersection_music = 0;
        //OrangutanLCD::clear();
        OrangutanLCD::print("No");
        OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
        OrangutanLCD::print("Stopping");

      }
      else {
        play_intersection_music = 1;
        OrangutanLCD::print("Do");
        OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
        OrangutanLCD::print("Stop");

      }
    }
  }

  OrangutanPushbuttons::waitForRelease(BUTTON_B);
  delay(1000);


  // Always wait for the button to be released so that 3pi doesn't
  // start moving until your hand is away from it.


  // Auto-calibration: turn right and left while calibrating the
  // sensors.
  for (counter=0; counter<80; counter++)
  {
    if (counter < 20 || counter >= 60)
      OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(40, -40);
    else
      OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(-40, 40);

    // This function records a set of sensor readings and keeps
    // track of the minimum and maximum values encountered.  The
    // IR_EMITTERS_ON argument means that the IR LEDs will be
    // turned on during the reading, which is usually what you
    // want.
    robot.calibrateLineSensors(IR_EMITTERS_ON);

    // Since our counter runs to 80, the total delay will be
    // 80*20 = 1600 ms.
    delay(20);
  }
  OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(0, 0);



  OrangutanLCD::clear();

  OrangutanLCD::print("Go!");       

  // Play music and wait for it to finish before we start driving.
  OrangutanBuzzer::playFromProgramSpace(go);
  while(OrangutanBuzzer::isPlaying());
}


// This function, causes the 3pi to follow a segment of the maze until
// it detects an intersection, a dead end, or the finish.
void follow_segment()
{
  int last_proportional = 0;
  long integral=0;

  while(1)
  {
    // Normally, we will be following a line.  The code below is
    // similar to the 3pi-linefollower-pid example, but the maximum
    // speed is turned down to 60 for reliability.

    // Get the position of the line.
    unsigned int position = robot.readLine(sensors, IR_EMITTERS_ON);
    if (!do_compass) 
      display_sensors();
    // The "proportional" term should be 0 when we are on the line.
    int proportional = ((int)position) - 2000;

    // Compute the derivative (change) and integral (sum) of the
    // position.
    int derivative = proportional - last_proportional;
    integral += proportional;

    // Remember the last position.
    last_proportional = proportional;

    // Compute the difference between the two motor power settings,
    // m1 - m2.  If this is a positive number the robot will turn
    // to the left.  If it is a negative number, the robot will
    // turn to the right, and the magnitude of the number determines
    // the sharpness of the turn.
    int power_difference = proportional/20 + integral/10000 + derivative*3/2;

    // Compute the actual motor settings.  We never set either motor
    // to a negative value.
    if (variable_speed)
      speed = random(1, 7);
    const int maximum = speed * 30; // the maximum speed
    if (power_difference > maximum)
      power_difference = maximum;
    if (power_difference < -maximum)
      power_difference = -maximum;

    if (power_difference < 0)
      OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(maximum + power_difference, maximum);
    else
      OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(maximum, maximum - power_difference);

    // We use the inner three sensors (1, 2, and 3) for
    // determining whether there is a line straight ahead, and the
    // sensors 0 and 4 for detecting lines going to the left and
    // right.

    //if (sensors[0] > 200 && sensors[1] > 200 && sensors[2] > 200 && sensors[3] > 200 & sensors[4]) {
    //  OrangutanBuzzer::playFromProgramSpace(go);
    //  while(OrangutanBuzzer::isPlaying()); 
    //}

    if (sensors[1] < 100 && sensors[2] < 100 && sensors[3] < 100)
    {
      // There is no line visible ahead, and we didn't see any
      // intersection.  Must be a dead end.
      return;
    }
    else if (sensors[0] > 200 || sensors[4] > 200)
    {
      // Found an intersection.
      return;
    }

  }
}


// Code to perform various types of turns according to the parameter dir,
// which should be 'L' (left), 'R' (right), 'S' (straight), or 'B' (back).
// The delays here had to be calibrated for the 3pi's motors.
void turn(unsigned char dir)
{
  if (play_intersection_music == 1) {
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(0, 0);
    OrangutanBuzzer::playFromProgramSpace(melody);
    while(OrangutanBuzzer::isPlaying());
  }
  switch(dir)
  {
  case 'L':
    // Turn left.
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(-80, 80);
    delay(200);
    if (current_direction == 'W')
      current_direction = 'S';
    else if (current_direction == 'E')
      current_direction = 'N';
    else if (current_direction == 'S')
      current_direction = 'E';
    else if (current_direction == 'N')
      current_direction = 'W';

    break;
  case 'R':
    // Turn right.
    if (current_direction == 'W')
      current_direction = 'N';
    else if (current_direction == 'E')
      current_direction = 'S';
    else if (current_direction == 'S')
      current_direction = 'W';
    else if (current_direction == 'N')
      current_direction = 'E';
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(80, -80);
    delay(200);
    if (do_calibration) {
      int counter;
      for (counter=0; counter<80; counter++)
      {
        if (counter < 20 || counter >= 60)
          OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(40, -40);
        else
          OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(-40, 40);

        // This function records a set of sensor readings and keeps
        // track of the minimum and maximum values encountered.  The
        // IR_EMITTERS_ON argument means that the IR LEDs will be
        // turned on during the reading, which is usually what you
        // want.
        robot.calibrateLineSensors(IR_EMITTERS_ON);

        // Since our counter runs to 80, the total delay will be
        // 80*20 = 1600 ms.
        delay(20);
      }
    }
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(0, 0);
    break;
  case 'B':
    // Turn around.
    if (current_direction == 'W')
      current_direction = 'E';
    else if (current_direction == 'E')
      current_direction = 'W';
    else if (current_direction == 'S')
      current_direction = 'N';
    else if (current_direction == 'N')
      current_direction = 'S';
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(80, -80);
    delay(400);
    break;
  case 'S':
    // Don't do anything!
    break;
  }
}


// The path variable will store the path that the robot has taken.  It
// is stored as an array of characters, each of which represents the
// turn that should be made at one intersection in the sequence:
//  'L' for left
//  'R' for right
//  'S' for straight (going straight through an intersection)
//  'B' for back (U-turn)
//
// Whenever the robot makes a U-turn, the path can be simplified by
// removing the dead end.  The follow_next_turn() function checks for
// this case every time it makes a turn, and it simplifies the path
// appropriately.
char path[100] = "";
unsigned char path_length = 0; // the length of the path

void display_sensors()
{
    unsigned int position = robot.readLine(sensors, IR_EMITTERS_ON);

  // Display the position measurement, which will go from 0
  // (when the leftmost sensor is over the line) to 4000 (when
  // the rightmost sensor is over the line) on the 3pi, along
  // with a bar graph of the sensor readings.  This allows you
  // to make sure the robot is ready to go.
  OrangutanLCD::clear();
  OrangutanLCD::print(sensors[0]/10);
  //OrangutanLCD::print(sensors[1]/10);
  //OrangutanLCD::print(sensors[2]/10);
  //OrangutanLCD::print(sensors[3]/10);
  //OrangutanLCD::print(sensors[4]/10);
  OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
  display_readings(sensors);
}

// Displays the current path on the LCD, using two rows if necessary.
void display_path()
{
  // Set the last character of the path to a 0 so that the print()
  // function can find the end of the string.  This is how strings
  // are normally terminated in C.
  path[path_length] = 0;

  OrangutanLCD::clear();
  OrangutanLCD::print(path);

  if (path_length > 8)
  {
    OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
    OrangutanLCD::print(path + 8);
  }
}

// This function decides which way to turn during the learning phase of
// maze solving.  It uses the variables found_left, found_straight, and
// found_right, which indicate whether there is an exit in each of the
// three directions, applying the "left hand on the wall" strategy.
unsigned char select_turn(unsigned char found_left, unsigned char found_straight, unsigned char found_right)
{
  i = i + 1;
  if (use_pattern) {
    if (pattern_loop) {
      return pattern[i % pattern_length];
    } 
    else if (i >= pattern_length) {
      stop_robot = 1;
      return 'B';
    } else {
      return pattern[i];
    }
  }
  // Make a decision about how to turn.  The following code
  // implements a left-hand-on-the-wall strategy, where we always
  // turn as far to the left as possible.
  if (be_random == 1) {
    if (found_left && found_straight && found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 4);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'L';
      if (picked_choice == 2)
        return 'S';
      if (picked_choice == 3)
        return 'R';
    }
    if (found_left && found_straight && !found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 3);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'L';
      if (picked_choice == 2)
        return 'S';
    }
    if (found_left && !found_straight && found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 3);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'L';
      if (picked_choice == 2)
        return 'R';
    }
    if (found_left && !found_straight && !found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 2);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'L';
    }
    if (!found_left && found_straight && found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 3);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'S';
      if (picked_choice == 2)
        return 'R';
    }
    if (!found_left && found_straight && !found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 2);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'S';
    }
    if (!found_left && !found_straight && found_right) {
      int picked_choice = random(0, 2);
      if (picked_choice == 0)
        return 'B';
      if (picked_choice == 1)
        return 'R';
    }
    if (last1 == 0)
      last1 = 1;
    else if (last2 == 0) 
      last2 = 1;
    else if (last3 == 0) 
      last3 = 1;
    else
      stop_robot = 1;
    return 'B';
  }
  else {
    if (found_left)
      return 'L';
    else if (found_straight)
      return 'S';
    else if (found_right)
      return 'R';
    else
      return 'B';
  }
}

// Path simplification.  The strategy is that whenever we encounter a
// sequence xBx, we can simplify it by cutting out the dead end.  For
// example, LBL -> S, because a single S bypasses the dead end
// represented by LBL.
void simplify_path()
{
  // only simplify the path if the second-to-last turn was a 'B'
  if (path_length < 3 || path[path_length-2] != 'B')
    return;

  int total_angle = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
  {
    switch (path[path_length - i])
    {
    case 'R':
      total_angle += 90;
      break;
    case 'L':
      total_angle += 270;
      break;
    case 'B':
      total_angle += 180;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Get the angle as a number between 0 and 360 degrees.
  total_angle = total_angle % 360;

  // Replace all of those turns with a single one.
  switch (total_angle)
  {
  case 0:
    path[path_length - 3] = 'S';
    break;
  case 90:
    path[path_length - 3] = 'R';
    break;
  case 180:
    path[path_length - 3] = 'B';
    break;
  case 270:
    path[path_length - 3] = 'L';
    break;
  }

  // The path is now two steps shorter.
  path_length -= 2;
}

// This function comprises the body of the maze-solving program.  It is called
// repeatedly by the Arduino framework.
void loop()
{
  if (!stop_robot || !stop_protection) {
    follow_segment();

    // Drive straight a bit.  This helps us in case we entered the
    // intersection at an angle.
    // Note that we are slowing down - this prevents the robot
    // from tipping forward too much.
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(50, 50);
    delay(50);
    if (!do_compass)
      display_sensors();

    // These variables record whether the robot has seen a line to the
    // left, straight ahead, and right, whil examining the current
    // intersection.
    unsigned char found_left = 0;
    unsigned char found_straight = 0;
    unsigned char found_right = 0;

    // Now read the sensors and check the intersection type.
    unsigned int sensors[5];
    robot.readLine(sensors, IR_EMITTERS_ON);

    // Check for left and right exits.
    if (sensors[0] > 100)
      found_left = 1;
    if (sensors[4] > 100)
      found_right = 1;

    // Drive straight a bit more - this is enough to line up our
    // wheels with the intersection.
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(40, 40);
    delay(200);

    // Check for a straight exit.
    robot.readLine(sensors, IR_EMITTERS_ON);
    if (sensors[1] > 200 || sensors[2] > 200 || sensors[3] > 200)
      found_straight = 1;

    // Intersection identification is complete.
    // If the maze has been solved, we can follow the existing
    // path.  Otherwise, we need to learn the solution.
    unsigned char dir = select_turn(found_left, found_straight, found_right);

    // Make the turn indicated by the path.
    turn(dir);
    if (do_compass) {
      OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(0, 0);
      OrangutanLCD::clear();
      OrangutanLCD::print(dir);
      OrangutanLCD::gotoXY(0, 1);
      OrangutanLCD::print(current_direction);
      if (current_direction == 'W')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a gafaeada");
      if (current_direction == 'E')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a gfgfgfgf");
      if (current_direction == 'S')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a efgefgef");
      if (current_direction == 'N')
        OrangutanBuzzer::play("!T240 L8 a abcabcab");
      while(OrangutanBuzzer::isPlaying());
    }

    // Store the intersection in the path variable.
    path[path_length] = dir;
    path_length++;

    // You should check to make sure that the path_length does not
    // exceed the bounds of the array.  We'll ignore that in this
    // example.

    // Simplify the learned path.
    simplify_path();

    // Display the path on the LCD.
    //display_path();
  }
  else {
    OrangutanMotors::setSpeeds(0, 0);
    if (!already_stopped) {
      OrangutanLCD::clear();

      OrangutanLCD::print("Stopped");   
      already_stopped = 1;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: This would be a better fit for the new [Robotics Stack Exchange Beta](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microcontroller controlled SD card + sound player modules are available for [around $6](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-WTV020-SD-16P-MP3-Voice-module-U-disk-audio-player-SD-card-voice-module-/281023238207?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item416e4a503f) (and up). These have a memory card reader, MP3, ADPCM or WAV file deciding, and PCM audio output, with a 0.1" header for connecting to the microcontroller board of choice. Your application can trigger specific files to be played back on events of interest.

So simply record the "north", "south", "east", "west" and any other speech into separate files, and play back the appropriate file as needed.

At a slightly higher price point, similar modules with a chip amplifier on board can be found, for louder sound output. Some of these modules offer stereo 3W + 3W or higher outputs, but stereo does not seem a requirement for the application described.